# Rails 4 Deprecation Warnings: Relation#calculate with finder options is deprecated. Please build a scope and then call calculate on it instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecation-warning

Below is the method in "Hotel" model for finding the top_spenders with respect to transactions and users.

```
def top_spenders
    top_spenders = []
    self.transactions.group(:user_id).sum(:amount, :order => 'SUM(amount) DESC', :limit => 5).each do |record|
        person = User.find(record.first).name 
        amount = record.second
        person_amount = [person, amount]
        top_spenders << person_amount
    end 
    top_spenders
end

### hotel.rb
    has_many :transactions

### transaction.rb
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :hotel
```

The line that gives Deprecation warnings is:

```
self.transactions.group(:user_id).sum(:amount, :order => 'SUM(amount) DESC', :limit => 5)
```

And the Deprecation warnings are as follows:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#calculate with finder options is deprecated. Please build a scope and then call calculate on it instead. (called from top_spenders ...
DEPRECATION WARNING: The :distinct option for `Relation#count` is deprecated. Please use `Relation#distinct` instead. (eg. `relation.distinct.count`). (called from top_spenders ...
```

I did try adding scope for the grouped transaction and then query sum in it but still the warning persisted. Also, tried some other ways but couldn't avoid the deprecation with the requirement fulfilled.

Any help would be greatly admired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.transactions.group("user_id").select("user_id, sum(amount) as total_amount").order("sum(amount) DESC").includes(:user)
```

This fixed the deprecation warning and also enabled the eager loading. Thanks to Rails 4. :)